# How to dynamically add fragment to Google Maps V2 FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm running google maps API V2 as FragmentActivity.

May activity layout is here: activity_landing.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

PROBLEM: I want to dynamically add a fragment to this layout FrameLayout.

Here is my activity code:

```
BuildingPageFragment buildingFragment = new BuildingPageFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, buildingFragment, "buildingPageFragment");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Here is the fragments layout that I am trying to add the the FrameLayout in activity_landing.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFBB00">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="BUILDING PAGE"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The Fragment is not shoing on top of the to the fragment in the activity_landing.xml.

I am new to android dev so what am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Do you wanna `add another fragment` on the map fragment or `instead of map fragment`? Better to here a screenshot to explain this

Comment: I want to add another fragment on top of the map. 
About the screenshot, I need to know how to construct the activity class xml layout. FrameLayout is not helping me since I dont have the Relative or LinearLayout tags there to put it in. Adding those tags crashes the app. Thanks for the question!

Comment: I updated the question and showed the changes I have done in the meanwhile.

Comment: I found that your code seems to be upside down. Exchange line `FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();` and `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, buildingFragment, "buildingPageFragment");`

Comment: How can you add to FragmentTransaction object before you declare it as FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();?
All examples online also use this kind of order.

Comment: [SOLVED]: I just needed to put the FrameLayout as a parent XML tag in activity_landing.xml.
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id=...>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id=.../>

</FrameLayout>

Comment: Oh.. I should aware of that, cuz I answered the similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28326783/4186942):) Thanks for the reminder.