# Overlay Fragment in Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I'm building an app and I'm trying to show a Fragment as an overlay to another fragment, which I know how to do following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300674/android-fragment-overlay-another-fragment-with-semi-transparent) question.

However, I'm using the Android Navigation Component and I'm trying to figure out how to show a fragment as an overlay instead of replacing the current visible fragment, when I navigate to it. Is there a way or it is still not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with the help of a reddit post, I used a [BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment), which is supported by Navigation Component v2.0.0 and on, which was however messing up my "back" button not turning into the burger menu button on the top most Fragment, so I ended up manually showing it by using `BottomDialogFragment().show(supportFragmentManager, "dialog")`

Getting the DialogFragment to be fullscreen was another pain, which I solved using this [medium post](https://medium.com/@oshanm1/how-to-implement-a-search-dialog-using-full-screen-bottomsheetfragment-29ceb0af3d41).

Hope this helps someone else as well.